# Kotlin kernel not connecting on jupyter notebook

Tags: kotlin, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I am trying to use kotlin kernel on jupyter notebook. I have jupyter notebook installed and it works good with Python. However, I am unable to connect to the kotlin kernel.

I have installed OpenJDK 20, have set it up on environment variables with names **JAVA_HOME** and **KOTLIN_JUPYTER_JAVA_HOME** for kotlin kernel to connect. I have both Javac and java interpreter accessible via command line as well. I also have installed Kotlin kernel using pip.

But it is not able to connect at all.
I am getting this error.

*A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.*

Appreciate your help with this. Thank you.

I tried resetting the kernel location, changing the OpenJDK locations, updating jupyter notebook but nothing worked till now. I tried starting the kotlin kernel using the direct cmd command but it gave me this error.

[image]

after some time, this error comes up which I am not able to understand.

[image]

I can still launch jupyter notebook, select the kotlin kernel but cannot run code in it. Python code runs fine.